# LXDE replace desktop with custom application

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, lxde, raspbian

I want to replace the desktop (not the docks, just the background and icons) on LXDE with a custom application.

That is, I want this:

[image: LXDE desktop]

to be replaced with this:

[image: custom app]

How do I set this up?  I'm not worried about the program I will run, I just need to know how to get it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: how is this different than having a "maximized" window? (except the missing "minimize, maximize, close" controls)

Comment: @wil93 It would always be there, and replace the desktop.  It would start with the DE and stick around.